# Offset Animation (Animation Nodes 2.0)

Tags: animation-nodes

Shift animation.
How to copy an animation from one object to another, and make a shift for each animation?

Comment: What do you mean by shift (spatial, temporal,...)? I don't think you can copy an AN to an object, but you can place several objects in a group and code an AN for the group. About the shift, it can be defined in a custom property of the objects and reached in AN using an expression node. If that can fit what you want and if you need more details I can write an answer with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Fcurves from the source object, and evaluate them with some frame offset fro some object. You can get the fcurves using the *FCurves From Object Node*, to identify what fcurve belong to what property, *FCurve Info Node* can be used where, for instance, the data path will be `location` for objects' location fcurve and the Array Index will be 0, 1, 2 for x, y, z respectively. Having identified the fcurves for the properties you want, for instance, locations. We can go ahead and evaluate them while setting some offset:

[image: Node Tree]

By viewing the results, we see that the object `Cube.001` lags behind the source object `Cube` by 5 frames (The offset we set):

[image: Result]

We can put that inside a loop to perform it for multiple object, where the offset will be a multiple of the index of the iteration:

[image: Loop]

Which results in:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! But what if i have some group objects. Every object have uniq position! What if i want that source animation start from uniq position every object in group. Every obj in group have uniq geomety. But what if i want that animation start from my selection set oj in group?

Comment: @SergeyGolubev Use the ID Keys option to store the initial location of each object, see [this](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/object/object_id_key.html). Then instead of using the evaliated fcurves vector as the location of the objects, add it to the initial locations and output the result.